# How to pass switches for a perl script which is run from tcl using exec

Tags: perl, tcl, exec

I generate a few variables in my tcl script which are actually used as switches for a perl script.

my switches are `-X`, `-Y` and `-Z`, I store them in a variable, `cmd` with
`set cmd "-X -Y -Z"`

I use exec to run the perl script in tcl like this:

```
exec ./script.pl $cmd
```

which throws an error: `"Error: Unknown option x -y -z"`

then I tried another way:

```
exec ./script.pl -- $cmd
```

For this particular case, the perl script gets executed but without the switches i.e. switches don't get activated.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I suspect your shell is parsing `-X -Y -Z` as *one* flag, you need to split them into three separate arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set cmd "-X -Y -Z"
```

Creates a single string with `-X -Y -Z` in it.  When you call the `exec` command with `exec ./script.pl $cmd`, you are passing a single argument with `-X -Y -Z`.  What you want are three separate arguments.  The best way to do this is:

```
 exec ./script.pl {*}$cmd
```

The `{*}` operator expands a list into its component words.

This is very useful.  You can build up your argument list with code similar to (an example):

```
set cmd {}
lappend cmd -X
if { $mytest eq "true" } {
   lappend cmd -Y 
}
lappend cmd -Z
if { $filename ne {} } {
  lappend cmd -f
  lappend cmd $filename
}
exec ./script.pl {*}$cmd
```

With older versions of Tcl, the `eval` command must be used:

```
eval exec ./script.pl $cmd
```

**Edit: -- argument to exec**

The `--` argument to `exec` specifies that no more switches (options) will be parsed by `exec`.   This allows `exec` to be used for the cases when a command starts with a `-`.   e.g.

```
 exec -- -myweirdcommand
```

References: [Tcl Syntax (#5)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm); [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm); [exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm)

Comment: Since, I run an older version of TCL, the 2nd solution worked for me. The 1st solution gave me an error: extra characters after close-brace.
 Anyways just out of curiosity, I wanted to know the usage of "--" in exec. Manual page says it marks the end of switches. Which specific case would this be used. I thought it will mark the end of switches for exec and would consider arguments for the perl script, but I was wrong.